# Reading a .dat fifo file and plot the data realtime

Tags: python, plot, pipe

I would like to know how can i open a pipe using python script to plot the data in the pipe in realtime.
the data in the pipe is as follows:

```
%time data_field1 data_field2

0 0.217413641411 0

0.001 0.202640969807 0

0.002 0.13284039654 0

0.003 0.111942324101 0

0.004 0.0806826346525 0
```

This data is being sent from a C++ file as an output.

In python, i would like read each line and update it in the graph realtime. 
can someone help me as how do i go about this

Thanku,

Answer (score 1):

Check this article: [Realtime plotting](http://hardsoftlucid.wordpress.com/various-stuff/realtime-plotting/), you can find there code samples for realtime plotting using `pylab` library. In your case you need more helpful values generator than `SinwaveformGenerator` (which produces just random numbers in example).

Comment: I am actually looking into reading the data shown above from a fifo via pipe and as this data is generated by another C++ program i finding it tough to understand how exactly i can read this file and also i will have to read only when new line of data is available.

Comment: I think `sys.stdin.readline()` in separated thread will be good enough for you task (to read from `stdin` you should call you script like `python plooting.py < ./datagenerator`).